# InDesign list alignment

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, lists

I'm trying to setup a list in InDesign and am wondering if there is a way to make multi-line points line up accordingly ***without*** forcing a break and inserting a tab character?

In the screenshot you can see the right side required a line-break and a tab to line up accordingly.

[image: Screenshot]

Following [the InDesign help](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/bullets-numbering.html):

> Increase the First Line Indent value if you want the punctuation in
>   long lists to be aligned. For example, if you want “9.” and “10.” to
>   be aligned on the period, change the Alignment to Right and gradually
>   increase the first line indent until the numbers align (make sure
>   Preview is turned on).
>
> To create the hanging indent effect, specify a positive Left Indent
>   value (such as 2p0), and then specify an equal negative value (such as
>   -2p0) for First Line Indent.

Following this it still isn't well aligned as in the example:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to align bullet point indent in InDesign paragraph styles?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57734/is-there-a-way-to-align-bullet-point-indent-in-indesign-paragraph-styles)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, just type this into the NUMBER field: `^#.^t`

Comment: Yes but then the wrapped line doesn't align properly? http://d.pr/i/zgYz/4Yd0jnWs

Comment: You must have tabs which are overwriting the indeting. Try clearing your tabs or redo the paragraph style - http://i.imgur.com/KvV1uom.jpg + http://i.imgur.com/68wX8jJ.jpg

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I make a list like yours, by default the lines wrap. Check your indent boxes on the top tool bar (circled in red below). 
[image]

Comment: Just to clarify his answer a little, you want to indent all lines by x, and then indent the first line by -x. This pushes all lines in by that amount and pulls the first line (with the number) back out again.