# How to align bulleted text in a paragraph style InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, paragraph-styles

[image]

Im creating a paragraph style right now and I want to make sure all the text is in line as you can see the second and third lines are indented. I've played around with the bullets and numbering, indents and spacing section but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Have tried the following in response to the same question from another user but still does not seem to do anything. See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to align bullet point indent in InDesign paragraph styles?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57734/is-there-a-way-to-align-bullet-point-indent-in-indesign-paragraph-styles)

Comment: I believe you need to adjust the left indent, first line indent, etc. in the Paragraph Styles> Style Options> Bullets and Numbering first to get your list lined up properly.  Then you can go into the Indents and Spacing for further adjusting. This is what the answer referred to in @AndrewH comment.

Answer (score -3):

You must use Indent to Here symbol.
[image]

Comment: No, you absolutely should **not** be abusing the _Indent To Here_ feature in this way. This should be handled with a bullet list and proper indenting.